# R Hive installation problems and troubleshooting

Tags: java, r, hadoop, hive

I am trying to use R for distributed text mining. The first step is to get Hive working on R on local machine.

So I executed the following steps:

1. Installed Hadoop on local machine
2. Launched R on the local machine. And installed rJava and Hive

The main problem I am running into is that Java libraries used by R's rJava and Hive are different than the ones used by Hadoop.

```
rJava uses java-6-openjdk
hadoop uses java-6-sun
```

Have you encountered this problem? Any leads?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: on linux, at least, you can set which jdk is preferred by using sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun. (Ubuntu) Not being familiar with either hive or rJava, i hope that this may prove useful

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Rhipe? Its a better option...check out this http://groups.google.com/group/brumail/browse_thread/thread/e403db404f039e31# Here i have used Rhipe 0.63, but in the latest version 0.66, while running the job you need to specify the location of library imperious.so in rhoptions function.